# If download takes more than 10 minutes (Circuit refresh time), what happens to circuit change?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I have a very slow internet (120kbps) and so even saving a small file takes 15 minutes on a good day. I read tor switches circuit every 10 minutes, but if download proceeds more than 10 minutes, does it keep using same circuit without changing new? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tor should keep the used circuit around until it isn't used anymore. (Aka your download finished.) Of course it *can* happen that a circuit dies even when it is in use. You *should* be able to resume a download successfully in most cases.
Checking download signatures is advised provided they are available.